# mikro-orm resolver does not save relational data after server restart

Tags: postgresql, graphql, typegraphql, mikro-orm

Post Entity

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Post {
  @Field()
  @PrimaryKey()
  _id!: number;

  @Field(() => String)
  @Property({ type: "date" })
  createdAt = new Date();

  @Field(() => String)
  @Property({ type: "date", onUpdate: () => new Date() })
  updatedAt = new Date();

  @Field()
  @Property({ type: "text" })
  title!: string;

  @Field()
  @Property({ type: "text" })
  text!: string;

  @Field(() => [Tag], { nullable: true })
  @ManyToMany(() => Tag, "posts", { owner: true, nullable: true })
  tags = new Collection<Tag>(this);
}
```

Tag Entity

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Tag {
  @Field()
  @PrimaryKey()
  _id!: number;

  @Field(() => String)
  @Property({ type: "date" })
  createdAt = new Date();

  @Field(() => String)
  @Property({ type: "date", onUpdate: () => new Date() })
  updatedAt = new Date();

  @Field()
  @Property({ type: "text" })
  name!: string;

  @Field(() => [Post], { nullable: true })
  @ManyToMany(() => Post, (posts: Post) => posts.tags, { nullable: true })
  posts = new Collection<Post>(this);
}
```

Post Resolver

```
  @Mutation(() => Post)
  async createPost(
    @Arg("options") options: PostInput,
    @Arg("_ids", () => [Int]) _ids: number[],
    @Ctx() { em }: MyContext
  ): Promise<Post> {
    const post = em.create(Post, {
      title: options.title,
      text: options.text,
      tags: em.getReference(Tag, [_ids]),
    } as RequiredEntityData<Post>);

    await em.persistAndFlush(post);
    return post;
  }
```

posts and tags are related with a many to many relation, which seems to work, but the behavior in apollo studio is very weird:

- whenever i create a new post, it only keeps the first id in the tags array(should have multiple tags)
- when i then query the posts, sometimes it return all the tags data(id, createdAt, updatedAt, name), and sometimes only the id
- no matter what, whenever I restart the server, the related data is not stored (post and tags are stored, but it says that post does not have tags)

i've tried to look at the docs and examples on github but after a couple of days i'm really stumped, so i'd appreciate some help

Comment: `tags: em.getReference(Tag, [_ids]),` this bit is wrong, you need to map the array instead: `tags: _ids.map(id => em.getReference(Tag, id)),`. The other points sound like you use global context. How do you define the `em` in context?

Comment: btw in fact you can just pass the array directly as `tags: _ids`

Comment: actually the first bullet point is also caused by this, only the second one sounds like context issue. https://mikro-orm.io/docs/identity-map

Comment: yep seems like it was, everything works perfectly now, thank you so much