# mikro orm forget the relationship between two entities when i restart the server

Tags: postgresql, graphql, mikro-orm

i have two entities 'Game' and 'GameMode' a game can have multiple game modes and a game mode belongs to a game

the issue is whenever i create a game and a game mode for it everything works fine until i restart the server then the relationship between the two disappears and i only get the game without it gameModes

**Creating a game**

```
    @Mutation(() => GeneralResponse)
     async createGame(@Ctx() { em }: MyContext,
     @Arg("name") name: string,
     ): Promise<GeneralResponse> {
        const game = em.create(Game, {
              active: true,
              category: Category.SPORTS,
              name: name,
        } as Game);
     await em.persistAndFlush(game);
     return { success: true };
    }
```

**Creating a gameMode for it**

```
    @Mutation(() => GeneralResponse)
      @UseMiddleware(Authentication)
      @UseMiddleware(Admin)
      async createGameMode(@Ctx() { em }: MyContext,
        @Arg("gameId") gameId: number,
        @Arg("name") name: string
      ): Promise<GeneralResponse> {
        const gameMode = em.create(GameMode, {
          Game: em.getReference(Game,gameId),
          name: name
        } as any);
        await em.persistAndFlush(gameMode);
        return { success: true };
      }
```

[image: Game Entity]

[image: GameMode Entity]

This is what happens when i restart the server

[image: GraphQL response after i restart the server]

i have tried to write raw sql for it it did not work same issue

Comment: Share some code, your entity definition looks correct. Sounds like you forget to call `em.flush()`.

Comment: @MartinAdámek Thanks for the reply, however That is not the issue in fact i get the right format of the data the first time with all the gameModes this issue occurs whenever i restart the server, i've added the resolver snippet you can check them now.

Comment: Enable debug mode and check what queries are fired.

Comment: How does your ORM config look like?

Comment: I have debug mode enabled in ORM config, and when i run the query i get this query fired select "g0".* from "game" as "g0"

Comment: and this query fires before and after i restart the server, and before it works and after i restart it doesn't anymore i just get the game with an empty array of game modes

Comment: i found someone that has 3 issues and one of them similar to mine but he only got the answer for the other two.     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72912062/mikro-orm-resolver-does-not-save-relational-data-after-server-restart

Comment: I told you to verify if you see correct `insert/update` queries, the select query is irrelevant.

Comment: Also I dont follow why should such select query fire on server load, again something you are doing, somewhere in code you are not sharing.

Comment: i don't fire the select query as soon as the server starts, i meant after restarting the server the link between the entities vanish

Comment: Here's the Insert query for Game:insert into "game" ("active", "category", "created_at", "name", "updated_at") values (true, 'Sports', '2022-11-09T13:52:12.858Z', 'FIFA 23', '2022-11-09T13:52:12.858Z') returning "id" [took 2 ms]

Comment: Here's the insert query for gameMode:        insert into "game_mode" ("created_at", "game_id", "name", "updated_at") values ('2022-11-09T13:52:15.965Z', 1, 'Online Seasons', '2022-11-09T13:52:15.965Z') returning "id"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by adding the "populate"

```html
@Query(() => [Game], { nullable: true })
  async games(@Ctx() { em }: MyContext): Promise<any> {
    const games = await em.find(Game, {}, {
      populate: ['gameModes'],
    });
    return games;
  }
```